# Differential Geometry-Hodge Star

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

The Hodge star is given by $$*(dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge....\wedge dx_{i_p})=\frac{1}{(n-p)!}e_{i_1 i_2....i_p i_{p+1}...i_n}dx^{i_{p+1}}\wedge dx^{i_{p+2}}\wedge....\wedge dx^{i_n}$$
The question is to prove $$**\omega_p=(-1)^{p(n-p)}\omega_p$$
by repeating the * operator on a p-form $\omega_p$. Now, how shall I prove it?
Here, $e_{ijk....}$ is antisymmetric tensor in n-dimension

Comment: I think there's one extra "$*$" in the first equation. Also, what do you mean by $e_{\cdots}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that in the formula you give us,
$$*(dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p})=\frac{1}{(n-p)!}e_{i_1 i_2\dots i_p i_{p+1}...i_n}dx^{i_{p+1}}\wedge dx^{i_{p+2}}\wedge....\wedge dx^{i_n},
$$
there is a summation involved! In fact, there are $n-p$ sums, since the indices are being contracted. **I won't use Einstein's convention in this post**.

Explicitly we have:
$$*(dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p})=\frac{1}{(n-p)!}\sum_{j_{p+1},\dots j_{n}=1}^ne_{i_1 i_2\dots i_p j_{p+1}...j_n}dx^{j_{p+1}}\wedge dx^{j_{p+2}}\wedge....\wedge dx^{j_n},
$$

where $e_{\cdots}$ is the [Levi-Civita tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).

In fact you're summing the same $(n-p)$-form $(n-p)!$ times! This follows from the definition of the Levi-Civita tensor and that $dx_i\wedge dx_j = -dx_j\wedge dx_i$.

To find how many times you're summing the same term observe that whenever an index is repeated, the term vanishes. In this case, the indices in the sum can take only $n-p$ distinct values and must all be different. So we get $(n-p)!$ possible combinations.

From this we get that (no sum involved!):
$$
*(dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p})=e_{i_1 \dots i_n}dx^{i_{p+1}}\wedge dx^{i_{p+2}}\wedge....\wedge dx^{i_n}.
$$
Now, applying again the star operator we get:
\begin{align}
**(dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p})
&=e_{i_1 \dots i_n}*dx^{i_{p+1}}\wedge dx^{i_{p+2}}\wedge....\wedge dx^{i_n}\\
&=e_{i_1\dots i_p i_{p+1}\dots i_n} e_{i_{p+1}\dots i_{n} i_1\dots i_{p}} dx^{i_1}\wedge dx^{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_p}.
\end{align}
To conclude, observe that
$$
e_{i_1\dots i_p i_{p+1}\dots i_n} e_{i_{p+1}\dots i_{n} i_1\dots i_{p}} = (-1)^{p(n-p)}.
$$
(To show this count how many permutations you must do on the second term to obtain the first.)

Comment: As I have already mentioned, here 'e' represents antisymmetric tensor in n- dimension, I should have better used epsilon symbol instead of 'e' for representing tensor. Now, how to proceed from here.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha So you're using Einstein's convention and there is a summation involved, right?

Comment: @ hjhjhj57 Sorry mate, but I am very new at this differential geometry, definitely have to review my earlier notes on tensor. I am as lost as ever. Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha feel free to ask if something's not clear.

Comment: Why we are not using (n-p)! in our proof ?

Comment: Also, I could not quite find out the last observation about levi civita symbol:How (-1)^p(n-p)

Comment: Sorry, but I am still unclear about the proof. My confusions are, why we don't use $\frac{1}{(n-p)!}$ in our proof, Why $e_{i_1\dots i_p i_{p+1}\dots i_n} e_{i_{p+1}\dots i_{n} i_1\dots i_{p}} = (-1)^{p(n-p)}$ I think there should also be $\frac{1}{(n-p)!}$ term in here.

Comment: $(a)$ The $1/(n-p)!$ term is introduced precisely to weight all the times we are summing the **same** term! $(b)$ If $e$ is an antisymmetric tensor what happens when you interchange to contiguous indices? What you must show is that $e_{i_1 \dots i_n} = (-1)^{p(n-p)}e_{i_{p+1}\dots i_n i_1 \dots i_p}$. You should try with an example, try with $n=2$ and $p=1$ and if it isn't clear enough, try $n=4$ $p=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with n=2 and p=1 and got the result, but I am not able to prove the relation with antisymmetric tensor though !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21579/discussion-between-hjhjhj57-and-roshan-shrestha).